# Have generic methods that transfer DTO's from different packages, but contain same fields

Tags: java, design-patterns, api-design, dto

I have 3 services Service **A**, **B**, **C** which put and get data to/from Service **D**

```
+============================================+
|   Service A  |   Service B  |   Service C  |
+============================================+
|       |              |              |      |
|--------------------------------------------|
|                  Service D                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Currently all 3 services **A**, **B** and **C** have exactly the same DTO's

So I have the same DTO in 3 different packages. Here example of the class

```
pulbic class TemplateDto {

    private Long    id;

    private String  name;

    private Integer someNumber

    setter()
    getter()
}
```

here the packages where the above DTO is contained:

```
com.test.serviceA.dto
com.test.serviceB.dto
com.test.serviceC.dto
```

I thought it's best to keep different DTO's for the future in case they change

In service **D** should I implement 3 different puts and gets for all the different DTO's or is there a better way
without having to produce so much duplicated code?

Comment: Do the DTO classes refer to data that is owned by services A,B or C, or is the data owned by service D?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau they refer to data owned by service D. But I thought the DTO's should differ because maybe service A needs one more field in the future that the others don't etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is you are added as `Service Reference` of these services and those `DTO` coming as `Proxy` classes.

Whether it is true or not, do not create any `D Service` method depends on `A, B or C services' DTO`. Create your own model and use it in your `D service` method. Just write mapper for `DTO to new model`. It will better solution to ignore duplicated methods.

If you also don't want to engage with same DTO coming from different service namespaces, you can create seperate dll library which contains DTO and use it all A, B, C and D service and cast the DTO by using third party dll like Newtonsoft.